# Allowing special characters in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, special-characters

I am allowing the user to input some data into the TextField. The user inputs `Š1234D` into the TextField.

The code I have looks like this:

```
NSString *string = textField.text;
for (int nCtr = 0; nCtr < [string length]; nCtr++) {
                const char chars = [string characterAtIndex:nCtr];
                int isAlpha = isalpha(chars);
}
```

string output looks like this:`Š1234D`
Then I printed the first chars value, it looks like this:'`' instead of 'Š'. Why is this so? I would like to allow special characters in my code as well.

Any suggestion would be welcome as well. Need some guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are truncating the character value as `[NSString chatacterAtIndex:]` returns `unichar` (16-bit) and not `char` (8-bit).  try:

```
unichar chars = [string characterAtIndex:nCtr];
```

**UPDATE**: Also note that you shouldn't be using `isalpha()` to test for letters, as that is restricted to Latin character sets and you need something that can cope with non-latin characters.  Use this code instead:

```
NSCharacterSet *letterSet = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
NSString *string = textField.text;
for (NSUIntger nCtr = 0; nCtr < [string length]; nCtr++)
{
    const unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:nCtr];
    BOOL isAlpha = [letterSet characterIsMember:c];
    ...
}
```

Comment: i get this as my result: $0 = 352 [no Objective-C description available]

Comment: wow, just made the same update but yours is better formatted.

Answer (score 3):

`characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar` (2-byte Unicode character), not `char` (1-byte ASCII character). By casting it to `char`, you are getting only one of the two bytes.

You should turn on your compiler warnings. I believe "Suspicious implicit conversions" should do the trick.

On a separate note, you can't use `isAlpha(char)` with a `unichar`. Use `[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:chars]`